# What happens if two players use Potion of Acquiescence on each other?

Tags: werewolv.es

If one or both players have other items, where do the items end up?

Instead of two potions it could also be a potion and a Thief, or two Thieves...

I assume the items would be swapped, this seems the most logical/fair. Some confirmation would be nice though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thefts are resolved simultaneously, so if Alice had item X and Bob had item Y and both tried to rob each other, Alice would end up with item Y and Bob with item X.

If the rob attempt was done with a potion, the potions would be consumed by the attempts and would not be stolen by the other player.